# can SQL insert using select return multiple identities?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, lastinsertid

I am insertnig into a table using a selection

```
INSERT california_authors (au_id, au_lname, au_fname)
SELECT au_id, au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
WHERE State = 'CA'
```

say i have an identity column in `california_authors`. Can i get all the ids inserted by the above particular insertion just like i can get @@IDENTITY for last `single insertion` ?

I can't use select command for `california_authors` as there may exists previously inserted records with filter `State = 'CA'`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

Something like this if your identity column is named `IdentityCol' will return you id's as a result set.

```
INSERT california_authors (au_id, au_lname, au_fname)
OUTPUT inserted.IdentityCol
SELECT au_id, au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
WHERE State = 'CA'
```

You can insert the id's to a table using `output ... into`.
Here is a sample that stores the id's in a table variable.

```
declare @IDs table (id int)

INSERT california_authors (au_id, au_lname, au_fname)
OUTPUT inserted.IdentityCol INTO @IDs
SELECT au_id, au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
WHERE State = 'CA'
```